# Can analysis be framed using only topology?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, reference-request

I'm looking for a text/monograph/book that treats analysis purely from the standpoint of topology (if possible), but I can't find one. What I mean by purely topological is the definitions and theorems of analysis are given and proven using topology. (Does this even make sense?)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, since topology is an integral part of real analysis. Can you give an example of a non-topological argument in real analysis that you would like to see replaced with a topological argument?

Comment: Topology is good at capturing notions of "closeness", which is only the start of analysis (limits and continuity).  To do analysis, you need some additional structure (a notion of "smoothness"), which is the domain of differential topology.  Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* is, I think, a fairly standard reference.

Comment: What about uniform continuity and all that involves -- do you want an exposition in the context of uniform spaces? In any event, a once fairly standard U.S. first year graduate level text in  real analysis (1960s), [**Real and Abstract Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387901388) by Hewitt/Stromberg (1965), brings in topology notions quite early, but somehow I don't think this is the type of book you're looking for. Maybe the Bourbaki volume [**Functions of a Real Variable**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/3540653406)?

Comment: There's also Dieudonné's [10-volume **Treatise on Analysis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treatise_on_Analysis), but again I don't think this is what you're looking for. You should be a bit more specific about your request, since as presently written I don't know if you're asking for undergraduate level, beginning graduate level, advanced graduate level, professional research level, etc., and your profile doesn't give any hint as to your background. Also, by "analysis", do you mean just real analysis, or also complex analysis, functional analysis, harmonic analysis, etc.?

Comment: Dieudonne's work is lovely.  Should be required reading. :D

Comment: @Xander Henderson: And once finished, say 10-15 years after beginning, one can then move on to other things, and maybe one day actually get to research!

Comment: Have yo heard about "topological **vector spaces**" ? This mixed algebraic-topological structure is a good starting block to do analysis. With topology alone, you will not go far.

Comment: analysis cannot be reduced to topology, by example completeness is not a topological notion, neither almost everywhere pointwise convergence

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I'm at an undergraduate level having gone through only Abbott's Understanding Analysis, so I'm just getting acquainted with the terminology and tools of analysis.

Comment: Some theorems/definitions can't even be expressed using pure topological language. For example the definition of derivative requires algebraic structure of $\mathbb{R}$ and so no theorem from the widely understood calculus can be done purely topologically.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the comments:
The short answer is no. There are many notions of real analysis which can't be reduced to topological notions, for example:

1. The notion of completeness in a metric space
2. Almost everywhere point convergence